# How to run ngspice from command line & suppress output to terminal?

Tags: simulation, circuit

I'm learning ngspice and would like to suppress the standard output on my terminal. I didn't see a corresponding option in the user manual and am wondering if I simply overlooked it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant solution but will do for now:

I simply pipe the output into a temporary text file.

```
ngspice -b -o <logfile> <circuitfile> > temp.txt
```